# Are there any non trivial polynomial identities in $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I am looking for all polynomials $f(x, y)$ such that $f(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) = 0$ $\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$

My hunch is that this ideal = $(x^2+y^2-1)$.

I came to this question while wondering when $I(V(I)) = \sqrt{I}$ for polynomials over real field.
I was studying Nullstellensatz when this question came to my mind.

So, starting with the prime ideal $x^2+y^2-1$ (irreducible in  a UFD) we get that $  I \subset I(V(I))$. I think equality holds but I am unable to prove.

I think this is an interesting question because if the equality holds then any polynomial identity in $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$ is generated by $x^2+y^2-1$.

I have been able to show that there are no such polynomials of degree $3$ that are not multiples of $x^2+y^2-1$. I started with taking some random expressions like $x^3+a_1x^2y+a_2y^2+a_3$ and showed by taking $x \to 1$ and hence $y \to 0$ and vice versa and so on to show that it is not possible.

Next  I looked at a 'generic' three degree polynomial that is not a multiple of $x^2+y^2-1$,
$g(x, y) = (x+ay)(x^2+y^2-1)+ bx^2+cx+dy+e$

Once again expanding and using $x^2+y^2-1 = 0$ and doing similar stuff we see that no such polynomial is possible.

I observe that in general for we can use $x^2+y^2-1 = 0$ to reduce the problem to: What are the polynomials of the form $P(y)+xQ(y)$ which vanish for all $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$?

From here I deduce a necessary condition: $y^2Q(y^2)+P^2(y) -1 =0$ but I dont know where to go from here.

Please help.