# Which Ideals and varieties correspond over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

We know that $\mathcal{I(V(}I)) = \sqrt{I}$ when the underlying field is algebraically closed. So, algebraic sets and radical idels correspond.

The question that I wonder about is how much relation of this holds for polynomials over the field $\mathbb{R}$?

Certainly we need $\mathcal{V}(I) \neq \emptyset$.
But certainly this is not sufficient. Take $x^2+y^2$(Easy to check).

So, First lets look at one variable polynomials. Here $\mathcal{I(V(}I)) = \sqrt{I}$ only holds for ideals generated by a  polynomial with only real roots. This is a complete and clean description.

So, my **question** is:  Do we have such descriptions, or at least sufficient conditions for $\mathcal{I(V(}I)) = \sqrt{I}$ in more variables case?. Is there something in terms of like if $\mathcal{V}(I)$ is sufficiently big? I say this because I considered the following example in one of my previous questions:

[Are there any non trivial polynomial identities in $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168702/are-there-any-non-trivial-polynomial-identities-in-cos-theta-and-sin-the)
and so $\mathcal{I(V}(x^2+y^2-1)) = (x^2+y^2-1)$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Is this  a conincidence? Can we derive any sufficient conditions at least in two variable case?

Comment: The Nullstellensatz works over all fields, but you need zero sets over the algebraic closure even if ideals use polynomials with coefficients over the original field. If $K$ is a field and $J$ is an ideal in $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $I(V_{\overline K}(J)) = \sqrt{J}$, where $V_{\overline K}(J)$ is the zero set of $J$ in $\overline{K}^n$, $I(V_{\overline K}(J))$ is the ideal of polynomials in $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ vanishing on $V_{\overline K}(J)$, and $\sqrt{J}$ is the radical ideal of $J$ in $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Try $K = \mathbf R$ and $J = (x^2+y^2)$; note $V_{\mathbf C}(J) \not= \emptyset$.

Comment: See [real radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_radical).

Comment: @KCd But I am looking for sufficient conditions for when $\mathcal{IV}(I) = \sqrt{I}$ even when we are only taking the roots over the base field. From what you have stated certainly if it turns out that the zeroes are in the base field itself even when are considering the closure then that gives a sufficient condition.

Comment: @KCd But for instance, the example I had about $\mathcal{IV}(x^2+y^2-1) = (x^2+y^2-1)$ when i take the variety over $\mathbb{R}$ only and note that the variety enlarges if take it over $\mathbb{C}$. So, my question is can we give a sufficient condition in the case when there are zeroes in the closure not in the base field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Theorem 5.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03127 will give you a sufficient condition. If $I$ is prime and $\mathcal V(I)$ contains a smooth real point, then the Theorem tells you that $\overline{\mathcal V_{\mathbb R}(I)}=\mathcal V(I)$. By definition of the Zariski closure, this is saying that
$$
\mathcal V(\mathcal I(\mathcal V_{\mathbb R}(I)))=\mathcal V(I)$$
We take $\mathcal I$ on both sides and we use the Nullstellensatz. Recall that $\mathcal I$ applied to anything results in a radical ideal:
$$ 
\mathcal I(\mathcal V_{\mathbb R}(I))=\sqrt{\mathcal I(\mathcal V_{\mathbb R}(I))}=\mathcal I(\mathcal V(\mathcal I(\mathcal V_{\mathbb R}(I))))=\mathcal I(\mathcal V(I))=\sqrt I$$
This explains why you see nice behavior in $(x^2+y^2-1)$, which cuts out a smoooth variety, as opposed to $(x^2+y^2)$, whose real point is singular.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the reference. After thinking along lines of @KCd (looking at the closure), I do observe see that $\overline{\mathcal V_{\mathbb R}(I)}=\mathcal V(I)$ is infact equivalent to what I am asking. In general $\mathcal{I(A)} = \mathcal{I(B)}$ iff $\overline{A} = \overline{B}$. This formalizes my intuition of needing $\mathcal{V}(I)$ to be big. Zariski Toplogy helps us state it. But I am two sections away from Smooth Points. Will see the paper first thing after that

Comment: Good luck!!!!!!